# ClassNotFoundException when using ActionBarSherlock starting Fragment with "newInstance"

Tags: tabs, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am converting Android 4.x code to use ActionBarSherlock so that our App can be compatible with Gingerbread.

So far so good, but it fails launching a new instance of a fragment.

My MainActivity extends `SherlockFragmentActivity` implements `ActionBar.TabListener`.

The code fails here where case is 0:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            mFragmentProjects = ProjectsFragment.newInstance(position);
            return mFragmentProjects;                                                      
        case 1:
            mFragmentContacts = FragmentPeople.newInstance(position, 0);
            return mFragmentContacts;               
        }
        return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
```

Where case is 0 it supposed to initialize the fragment but I get this exception:
`ClassNotFoundException`. The only other clue I have is:
"this" in `PathClassLoader` and in "name" it says `android.app.ActionBar$TabListener`

I guess this has something to do with TabListener or libraries not included / loading correctly? **I have already cleaned the project**.

The fragment ProjectsFragment extends `SherlockListFragment`.

newInstance is pretty straitforward:

```
static ProjectsFragment newInstance(int num) {
    ProjectsFragment f = new ProjectsFragment();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", num);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that although MainActivity has no reference to ActivityY, the mere fact that ActivityY did not have the SherlockFragment code made it fail. To describe this differently:

MainActitivy uses ProjectsFragment which is a list
When you click on a list in ProjectsFragment it calls ListsActivity
ListsActivity references ItemsFragment

I had to change ItemsFragment to Sherlock code before MainActivity would work. It seems Java "looks ahead" in some way when you're working with pagers and tabs and fragments.